# jQuery and position:relative messing my hover up! Why?

Tags: jquery, css

so i have a little problem with placing a hover tooltip with jquery - if the "position" attribute in my css for a parent div is set to "relative" then the tooltip flies away to the top left of the screen. If i remove the position attribute, then all is well in the world and the tooltip comes back.

I don't really *get* jQuery or css positioning rules too well, so the questions are:

1. why does the position:relative mess up the jQuery tooltip placement?
2. if i did need the position:relative (and i don't), what could i do to resolve the problem?

the relevant code is:

```
$("yay").hover(
 function(){
     // .position() uses position relative to the offset parent,
     var pos = $(this).position();
     // .outerWidth() takes into account border and padding.
     var width = $(this).outerWidth();

     var messageToLoad = dumpArray[$(this).attr('class')];
     $(messageToLoad).css({
         left: (pos.left + width) + "px",
         top: pos.top + "px",
         position: "absolute",
         "visibility":"visible",
         "display":"inline"
     });
 },
```

and then the (offending) css is:

```
.content {
    margin: 0 0 0 35px;
    position:relative;
}
```

and the html is:

```
...
<tr class="PostOdd">
    <td>
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="content">
            <p> Brand new post goes here</p>
            <p class="postDate">June 15, 2012, 4:02 a.m.</p>
            <p class="options">
                <a href="/comments/1/1">
                    <img class="yay" src="/static_files/chat-icon.png">
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

UPDATE:

a. i am using jquery only, no other java plugins at all

b. if i remover the "position" attribue to the parent in the css file, then everything works normally. Actually, i have removed it, so this isn't a problem so much as a curiosity thing for me. I'm working on another section - if i don't get an answer by the time i'm done with that section, i'll whip up a jfiddle demo

Comment: create a simplified demo in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).... you haven't provided enough code to troubleshoot with, especially using bogus selectors like `yay`

Comment: usually you apply `relative` to the parent containers style, then `absolute`, `fixed`, or something else to the child element assuming your wanting to keep within the confines of the parent element. Parent and Child with relative set on both can sometimes lead to messy unexpected behavior (from my own experience at least)

Comment: Please answer these questions. 1) Are you using a jQuery plugin or you've created this Javascript code? If you are using a plugin, what is it? 2) If you remove the `position relative` atribute, will you get some problem in your layout?

Comment: @masimao answers added to the question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is happening because the DIV ".content" is the first positioned element. For example, see this structure:

```
<div class="great-grandfather">

    <div class="grandfather">

        <div class="father">

            <div class="son">

                <img class="yay" src="/static_files/chat-icon.png">

            <div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

When you put the mouse over the image with the class "yay", as it is set with `position: absolute`, the reference for your position is the first parent element that have a **relative** or **absolute** position property.

If the DIV ".son" has a position relative or absolute, the ".yay" image will coordenate your position according ".son". If is ".father" has, according ".fahter" and so on.

If all parents have a position property, can be relative or absolute, will be considered the first parent element, in this case ".son".

Hope i can help you with this explanation, if you have some doubt, please leave a comment and i will edit the answer.

Comment: i like what you're saying - so if i has the "son" set to "position:relative", then what would i need to do to have the co-ord for ".yay" set to absolute? Setting position:absolute for ".yay" didn't work for me

Comment: Try to set the `.yay` with `position:absolute;` and `.son` with `position:relative;`

Comment: You must look the JQuery code too, i think your problem is in event `hover()`, more specifically in the `.css()` method. Do some tests changing the values to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add z-index to your content class like this:

```
.content {
    margin: 0 0 0 35px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```